# Question about a redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url-routing, redirect

I just noticed that sometimes (even when given a wrong url) load perfectly fine. How do they accomplish this? What I mean is, suppose you click on a link that seems good like www.foo.com but it contains in the end a space character which would appear on the address bar as www.foo.com%20 some sites manage to redirect this to their correct url while others just break. How can this be achieved? I'm guessing it's something to do with the .htaccess but I have no idea what to do or where to do it.

The URL I'd like to redirect looks like this actually: http://foo.com/%C2%A0

I get the following error message:

> The requested URL /%C2%A0 was not found on this server.

How can I make this redirection?
So far I came up with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^%?\ ]*\%
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.foo.com/ [R=301,L]
```

but it's not working at all

Comment: I'm not that much into redirection (and this cannot give you a real line) but you'll wanna make everything past the % disappear, so to speak. Just a heads up to whoever it may concern :)